# Python Multi-Processing -- Array Sharing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When sharing a `rawarray` between different processes using `multiprocessing`, is it a problem to have all the children write / modify the `raw array`?

Does one need to handle lockings etc in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python documentation:

> multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray(typecode_or_type,
>   size_or_initializer)
>
> ```
> Return a ctypes array allocated from shared memory.
>
> typecode_or_type determines the type of the elements of the returned
> ```
>
> array: it is either a ctypes type or a
>   one character typecode of the kind
>   used by the array module. If
>   size_or_initializer is an integer then
>   it determines the length of the array,
>   and the array will be initially
>   zeroed. Otherwise size_or_initializer
>   is a sequence which is used to
>   initialize the array and whose length
>   determines the length of the array.
>
> ```
> Note that setting and getting an element is potentially non-atomic;
> ```
>
> use Array() instead to make sure that
>   access is automatically synchronized
>   using a lock.

So, you may need to use [multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array) which allows locking and synchronization between processes.

Comment: Thank you. I do care about atomicity. Is it possible to define a multi-dimensional array using `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array`?